# Magento 2 : Terms and Conditions Issue

Tags: magento2, bug, terms-and-conditions

I've added a second checkbox to terms and conditions, but that is not validating.

What I've done:

I've serached and found that, iIt was or is still an magneto2 bug, but found this: https://github.com/bka/magento2/blob/6d172c93a8deaccb0b5d1449cd3b7dc6fc9e8626/app/code/Magento/CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/web/js/model/agreement-validator.js
I've added this code but it isn't working.

After adding the code I tried following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

It's still not working.

Can Someone help with adding exact code that I have to replace?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have face the same issue(terms and conditions not validating) in our system, and change the below mentioned code. Now working properly.

**File Path:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/web/js/model/agreement-validator.js

**Change the below code:**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'mage/validation'
    ],
    function ($) {
        'use strict';
        var checkoutConfig = window.checkoutConfig,
            agreementsConfig = checkoutConfig ? checkoutConfig.checkoutAgreements : {};

        var agreementsInputPath = '.payment-method._active div.checkout-agreements input';

        return {
            /**
             * Validate checkout agreements
             *
             * @returns {boolean}
             */
            validate: function() {
                var noError = true;
                if (!agreementsConfig.isEnabled || $(agreementsInputPath).length == 0) {
                    return noError;
                }

                $('.payment-method:not(._active) div.checkout-agreements input')
                    .prop('checked', false)
                    .removeClass('mage-error')
                    .siblings('.mage-error[generated="true"]').remove();

                $(agreementsInputPath).each(function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');

                    var result = $('#co-payment-form').validate({
                        errorClass: 'mage-error',
                        errorElement: 'div',
                        meta: 'validate',
                        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                            var errorPlacement = element;
                            if (element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {
                                errorPlacement = element.siblings('label').last();
                            }
                            errorPlacement.after(error);
                        }
                    }).element(agreementsInputPath + '[name="' + name + '"]');

                    if (!result) {
                        noError = false;
                    }
                });

                return noError;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**After changed the code you will following command:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: hi @Sankar, tried this solution didn't work for me

Comment: @jafarpinjar Your magento version??

Comment: I am using 2.2.4